# onSensorChanged of android device

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have the long and lat from the android device but my result isn't good enough. I mean my result is int number : 37.0 or 260.0 .. I want it double number 37.001 - 37.999

My code :

```
// record the compass picture angle turned
private float currentDegree = 0f;
// device sensor manager
private SensorManager mSensorManager;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);
    tvHeading.setText(Float.toString(degree));
    // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree,
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
    // how long the animation will take place
    ra.setDuration(210);
    // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
    ra.setFillAfter(true);
    // Start the animation
    currentDegree = -degree;
 //   updateWithNewLocation(l);
}
```

Hope to help. Thanks.

Problem solved : need to definition degree like this :

```
float degree = event.values[0];
```

**Another problem is :**
My result is between 0.0 to 360.0 , I want the result acurate between 0.000 to **6400.999**

Problem solved too :
to make the degree between 0 - 6400 than do :

```
double result =degree * 17.77777778; 
         degree = (float) result;
```

lets take a example : 3200 must be 180 .. 180 * 17.77777778 is 3200 exactly. Thanks any way. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

degree should be defined as

```
  degree = Math.round(yourValue*100.0)/100.0;
```

for 2 digit round after decimal multiply and divided by 100

for 3 digit round after decimal multiply and divided by 1000

.
.
.

so on

Comment: i have edit the answer check it out. if it work kindly tick my answer and also vote up my answer.

Comment: I solved it by my self I editted the question. You can take a look. Thanks any way.

Comment: it's hardcoding. i am mentioning you the math logic. simple.